# How many strings of length 10 over the alphabet {a, b, c} are such that:

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

**a)** contain 3 letters a and the number of the letters b is greater than the number
of letters c?

**b)** all a's are before all b's?

Not sure but I think in the first one it's a permutation with repetition: $$\frac{10!}{3!7!} + \frac{10!}{3!6!1!}+ \frac{10!}{3!5!2!} + \frac{10!}{3!4!3!}$$

Comment: Assuming (a) is a completely separate question from (b), your answer for (a) is almost correct.  You seem to have just left off the factorial symbols from each of the numerators.  It would also have helped organize thoughts to help the reader by writing the terms in the denominator in alphabetical order rather than ascending order in order to emphasize the $3!$ has to do with the number of $a$'s, the $5!$ relates to the number of $b$'s and the $2!$ for the number of $c$'s for instance, so $\frac{10!}{3!7!0!}+\frac{10!}{3!6!1!}+\frac{10!}{3!5!2!}+\frac{10!}{3!4!3!}$

Comment: For (b) and/or for including the condition for (b) into the first problem... consider just picking the places for the c's.  Once you have done so, all remaining positions must be occupied by a's and b's and the first however many of which must all be a's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a: You have $3$ a's so you need to pick their places (${10 \choose 3}$ options) and there are 7 spots to fill with two possible letters. There are $2^7$ possibilities, out of which half have more $b$s and half more $c$, so in total: ${10 \choose 3}2^6$.

As pointed out in the comments, your way is almost correct too.

For b: You have $10$ possibilities for the number of $c$s. Suppose you choose to have $k$ of them. Then you need to find places for them (${10 \choose k}$ options) and then decide how to split the remaining $10-k$ letters into $a$ and $b$s. There are $10-k+1$ options ($0,1,...,10-k$) for the number of $a$s and they all must be placed first.
In total, the number of words is
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{10} {10 \choose k}(11-k)=6144$$
where the sum is calculated using known combinatorical indetities.